# error message with handling RequestQueue in Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Hi :) I have researched and I nowhere find solution to solve the problem in android with error message "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable javascript to your browser or use browser with javascript support"? I have included javascript into my browser..in response returns html tags with this message about javascript instead "hello from server!!!!!!!!"..

This program is simple server request using volley and should be printed on the screen "hello from server!!!!!!!!" in textView...

below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private String server_url = "http://donjikrivaj.byethost7.com/greatings.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getServerDataButton);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverTextView);


    }

    public void getDataServerListener(View view) {
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                textView.setText(response);
                requestQueue.stop();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("Something went wrong.........");
                error.printStackTrace();
                requestQueue.stop();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

please help, I'm desperate :/

Comment: I have this question too ...